# Prism 4: How to hide items in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, prism, prism-4

I am creating a Prism 4 demo app to learn the new framework, focusing on view-switching. The app has several regions, one of which is an ItemsControl that holds one or more buttons from the currently-active module.

I am registering the buttons with the Region Manager in each module's `Initilize()` method. Here is the registration code for the first module:

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ButtonRegion", typeof(ModuleAButton1));
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ButtonRegion", typeof(ModuleAButton2));
```

The second module registers its buttons the same way. I use `RequestNavigate()` to switch between the two modules.

Here's my problem: The buttons from both modules are visible in the `ItemsControl`, instead of just the buttons from the active module. I considered changing the `ItemsControl` to a `ContentControl` and putting the buttons in a `StackPanel`, but for reasons I won't bore you with here, that won't work for me. What I need to do is either:

- Load the buttons when a module is activated, and unload them when I switch to the other module, or
- Show the buttons when a module is activated, and hide them when I switch to the other module.

How do I do that in Prism 4? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. Implement the `IRegionMemberLifetime` interface on the view or its view model. The interface is made up of a single read-only boolean property, `KeepAlive`. If the property is set to `true`, the view will be kept alive after the user navigates away from it. If the property is set to `false`, the view will be unloaded. See the "Developers Guide to Microsoft Prism" (Ver 4), p. 121.